# Are there any security implications with enabling "Data Access" on a sever?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, availability-groups, openrowset

I'm trying to run an OPENQUERY statement within a local server but am getting the following error:

> Server 'MyLocalServer' is not configured for DATA ACCESS.

If I set MyLocalServer's Data Access option to true, what are the potential security implications?

Also can this affect anything with an AlawaysOn AG that MyLocalServer is a part of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling Data Access is not considered a finding in the [CIS Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Benchmark](https://www.cisecurity.org/benchmark/microsoft_sql_server/) but that doesn't mean it couldn't be a problem if it's poorly implemented.

If you are querying data on another server limit the privileges granted to the remote user.

Comment: So I'm using OPENQUERY locally but still need to enable that option otherwise it defaults with the "not configured for DATA ACCESS" error.

Comment: @J.D.  you can still apply best practice for querying locally.  Is there personally identifiable information? Has anyone from the business signed off on this access? Can you limit the query to a select?